# How to perform oracle query optimizely?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In oracle, for the question

Which country has a population that is more than Canada but less than Poland? Show the name and the population

I have done this way.

```
select name,population from world 
where population > (select population from world where name='Canada') 
and population< (select population from world where name ='Poland')
```

Is there any other optimized way?

Comment: What is the explain plan?

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with the query - although you provide no details about indexing. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: There is subquery in two places. I just wanted to know if there is any easy and optimized way this query could be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
WITH can_pol
     AS (SELECT SUM (DECODE (name, 'Canada', population)) pop_can,
                SUM (DECODE (name, 'Poland', population)) pop_pol
           FROM world)
SELECT name, population
  FROM world, can_pol
 WHERE population > pop_can 
   AND population < pop_pol;
```